# Kubernetes user format

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, k8s-serviceaccount

I'm trying to create a pipeline to deploy on Kubernetes. I get an error that the user "`system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:default`" doesn't have permission to read secrets.

I've installed `gitlab-runner` in the same my-namespace with all the possible roles.

However, I don't understand the 4th part of the user and why it's the **default**. Maybe if I know that, I can figure out how to give permission to read the secrets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The 4th part is the service account name, that is available as default.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3841

Comment: oh interesting I was hoping the gitlab-runner serviceaccount was in charge to deploy.. thanks!